# Maven dependency conflicts during test (surefire) but not production

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I have an application which requires a couple different versions of the same libraries. When running through intellij this isn't a problem because it exports the classpath in a way that avoid the conflicts. I then use the maven shade plugin to create an uber-jar when compiling for production.

However when using the surefire plugin to run my unit tests the conflicts appear again. Does anyone know a way that I can ensure that the sure-fire plugin creates the class path in a way to avoid these conflicts?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Below is the error I am getting (Although it is fairly specific to my application). Basically there are two versions of Saxon HE and PE which are both being loaded. When running the surefire tests it causes this exception:

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.jorsek.appserver.bootstrap.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:130)
    at com.jorsek.appserver.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:449)
    at framework.TestUtils.startupDatabase(TestUtils.java:41)
    at framework.AbstractTestInstance.startDatabase(AbstractTestInstance.java:41)
    at framework.AbstractTestInstance.startDatabase(AbstractTestInstance.java:55)
    at org.jorsek.exist.versioning.AllSetslTest.setUpBeforeClass(AllSetslTest.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:103)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory: Provider com.saxonica.config.ProfessionalTransformerFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/saxonica/config/ProfessionalConfiguration, method: newExpressionParser signature: (Ljava/lang/String;ZLnet/sf/saxon/value/DecimalValue;)Lnet/sf/saxon/expr/ExpressionParser;) Wrong return type in function
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:207)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:164)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:360)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:428)
    at org.exist.validation.XmlLibraryChecker.check(XmlLibraryChecker.java:162)
    at com.jorsek.appserver.jetty.JettyStart.<init>(JettyStart.java:95)
    at com.jorsek.appserver.jetty.JettyStart.main(JettyStart.java:77)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/saxonica/config/ProfessionalConfiguration, method: newExpressionParser signature: (Ljava/lang/String;ZLnet/sf/saxon/value/DecimalValue;)Lnet/sf/saxon/expr/ExpressionParser;) Wrong return type in function
    at com.saxonica.config.ProfessionalTransformerFactory.<init>(ProfessionalTransformerFactory.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:356)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: Can you attach example conflict error?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can override the other dependency on test scope as well? Or if need be, just override them both on default scope. Or is there some reason why you cannot do either of the above?

Or an alternative of course is to start dabbling with the classloader during your test runs, like shown [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html).